# Parse.com XMLHttpRequest failed: could not access to dashboard and db

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I try to access to my Parse.com dashboard and db, however it cannot be access since yesterday.

I researched on web but there is no clue.

Here is error code.

> XMLHttpRequest failed: {"statusText":"","status":0,"responseURL":"","response":"","responseType":"","responseXML":null,"responseText":"","upload":{"ontimeout":null,"onprogress":null,"onloadstart":null,"onloadend":null,"onload":null,"onerror":null,"onabort":null},"withCredentials":false,"readyState":4,"timeout":0,"ontimeout":null,"onprogress":null,"onloadstart":null,"onloadend":null,"onload":null,"onerror":null,"onabort":null}

After appearing avobe message, request is time outed.

My app status is dev mode(has not released my ios app). I suppose it is cause but not sure.
Sorry for my English.
Does anyone faced same issue?

Thanks in Advance!